# jsf page action listioner not working

Tags: jsf, richfaces

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">
    <h:head>
        <title>Community</title>

    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <rich:panel>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Login form" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:form id="loginform">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" width="210">
                    <rich:validator  id="loginformvalidate">                
                        <h:outputText value="Username:" />
                        <h:inputText label="username" id="username" value="#{loginMB.username}" required="true" requiredMessage="user name is requried">
                            <f:validateLength minimum="5" />
                        </h:inputText>                    

                        <h:outputText value="Password" />
                        <h:inputSecret label="password" id="password" value="#{loginMB.password}" requiredMessage="password is requried">
                            <f:validateLength minimum="8" maximum="16" />
                        </h:inputSecret>

                    </rich:validator>

                    <rich:notifyMessages  stayTime="2000" nonblocking="true"  />

                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <a4j:commandButton value="Login"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>

        </rich:panel>
        <rich:panel>
                    <h:form id="Questions">
                        <rich:dataTable value="#{contentBean.questions}" var="list" id="question" >
                            <rich:column>#{list.QUserid.fname}</rich:column><br/>
                            <rich:column> <rich:collapsiblePanel expanded="false" header="#{list.questionValue}" switchType="client" onclick="#{contentBean.onclick(list.qid)}" >
                                    <rich:accordion id="answer" switchType="ajax">
                                        <a4j:repeat value="#{contentBean.ansList}" var="skinName" >
                                            <rich:accordionItem name="#{skinName.ansDate}">
                                                #{skinName.ansValue}

                                            </rich:accordionItem>
                                        </a4j:repeat>
                                    </rich:accordion></rich:collapsiblePanel></rich:column>
                            <br/><rich:column>
                                  <h:commandButton value="Show popup">
                                            <rich:componentControl target="popup" operation="show">
                                                    <a4j:param noEscape="true" value="event" />
                                                    <rich:hashParam>
                                                            <f:param name="width" value="500" />
                                                            <f:param name="height" value="300" />
                                                            <f:param name="minWidth" value="300" />
                                                            <f:param name="minHeight" value="150" />
                                                            <a4j:param noEscape="true" name="left" value="(jQuery(window).width()/2)-250" />
                                                            <a4j:param noEscape="true" name="top" value="(jQuery(window).height()/2)-150" />
                                                        </rich:hashParam>
                                                </rich:componentControl>

                                        </h:commandButton>
                                 <rich:popupPanel id="popup" modal="false" autosized="true" resizeable="false">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="Add your answer" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <p>Enter your answer in less than 4000 char</p>

                                    <p>
                                        <h:inputTextarea id="answertxt" value="#{contentBean.ansvalue}" required="true"  requiredMessage="this feild is required"/>
                                        <h:commandButton value="Submit" onclick="#{rich:component('popup')}.hide(); return false;">
                                            <a4j:actionListener  for="Submit"  listener="#{contentBean.addAnswer(list.QUserid,list.QGroupid, list)}"/>

                                        </h:commandButton>


                                    </p>
                                </rich:popupPanel>
                            </rich:column>
                        </rich:dataTable>
                    </h:form>
        </rich:panel>


    </h:body>
</html>
```

I am new to jsf and richfaces i am tring to create two panels in singles with different forms can i do that?  the page worked until i have added new button which uses action listener in a popup window

i am getting following error

```
INFO: WEB0671: Loading application [My_community] at [/My_community]
INFO: My_community was successfully deployed in 19,911 milliseconds.
SEVERE: /index.xhtml @21,61 id="loginformvalidate" Unhandled by MetaTagHandler for type org.richfaces.component.behavior.ClientValidatorImpl
```

the page runs but submit button on popup generated action listener is not working
please let me know if i am doing any thing wrong

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure, rich:validator can have children ? I think it should be inside the fields you want to validate:

```
<h:inputText label="username" id="username" value="#{loginMB.username}" required="true" requiredMessage="user name is requried">
    <f:validateLength minimum="5" />
    <rich:validator/>
</h:inputText>
```